# How do I acquire Holy Water as a Cleric in 1st Edition Advanced Dungeons and Dragons?

Tags: cleric, equipment, adnd-1e

I've looked through the 1st Edition Player's Handbook but cannot find any reference to acquiring Holy Water. Is this something I can create as a level 1 Acolyte or does it need to be acquired from a stronger Cleric until a later level?

I have read and know the answer for 5E ([Can clerics create holy water?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55526/can-clerics-create-holy-water)), I am only interested in 1st Edition.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The *Player's Handbook* lists holy water as available for purchase for 25 gp on page 36 under Religious Items as *Water, Holy, vial.*

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* contains instructions for clerics on how to manufacture holy (and unholy) water on pages 114-115 in the section entitled Creation of Holy/Unholy Water. Since the instructions run about 500 words *and* are in the *DMG*, it's probably a good idea to ask the DM directly how it's done in that DM's campaign.

Comment: Ah, didn't find it because was searching for the string "Holy Water" and it doesn't word it that way on the page. Perfect!

Answer (score -1):

### At first level, you can't yet do it

> As a third level spell is involved, it requires a cleric of not less than 5th level of experience to manage to create such fluid.  (DMG, p. 114)

#### If you can get a higher level cleric to help you ...

From the DMG you will find the following requirements:

1. A holy water font is required (details in the DMG at pages 114/115).
   What your acolyte must do is find a temple/shrine/church/holy ground
   that includes a *holy water font*.
2. Then ally with or convince (or
   pay) an NPC cleric that can cast the 2nd and 3rd level Chant and
   Prayer to perform the ceremony.  Your first level cleric could
   assist. Your acolyte can, however, bring various
   receptacles/containers/vials, as noted below.
3. Spells that must be cast over the font:

   1. create water
   2. purify food & drink (the water) or its reverse
   3. bless or its reverse
   4. chant ( 1 full turn)
   5. prayer

   > Once created, the holy/unholy water cannot leave the font far more
   >   than a turn without losing its efficacy unless it is placed within
   >   specially blessed/cursed vials of crystal - either rock or special
   >   leaded glass. Each empty vial is worth 2-5 gold pieces. (DMG p. 115)

As there are a lot of details involved in this process, you'll want to work with the DM on all of the details so that preparation, preparing the containers to fill with holy water, interaction with the NPC, and the ceremony itself all come together.