# Can a vial of holy water be used as a weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, equipment

In the *Player’s Handbook* the section for holy water states (emphasis mine):

> As an action, you can splash the contents of this **flask** onto a creature within 5 feet of you or throw it up to 20 feet, shattering it on impact. In either case, make a ranged attack against a target creature, treating the holy water as an improvised weapon. If the target is a fiend or undead, it takes 2d6 radiant damage.

In both *Curse of Strahd* and *Storm King’s Thunder* characters can find *vials* of holy water, not flasks. These could be used as a material component for certain spells, but can they be used a weapon like a flask of holy water? If so, how would the damage differ?

The *Player’s Handbook* also defines the capacity of a vial as “4 ounces liquid” and a flask (or tankard) as “1 pint liquid”. So could a character combine four vials to use as a weapon?

Comment: _Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage_ also includes a vial of holy water, in level 1, area 7b.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### There are many items left undefined; they are left up to the GM

There are several items in the PHB which are left undefined, such as the Mess Kit, Grappling Hook, Hammer, and Chain; and others are added in *Curse of Strahd* such as garlic, salt, and vials of holy water. None of these are specifically defined in the rules so how they work would be left up to a GM. The only thing I could find that vials of holy water would explicitly do is work as a material component for spell which require amounts of holy water.

It is certainly reasonable to use the descriptions of vial and flask in determining these effects:

> A vial can hold up to 4 ounces of liquid.
>
> A flask holds 1 pint of liquid.

There are sixteen ounces in a pint, so there would be four vials in one flask. Perhaps then a vial deals one-fourth the damage of a flask.

Also note that those are not the only times vials of holy water exist, the [*ceremony*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ceremony) spell states:

> [...] **Bless Water**. You touch one vial of water and cause it to become holy water.

Comment: A question related to your *ceremony* reference: [Is Ceremony required to make holy water?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122652/is-ceremony-required-to-make-holy-water)

Comment: In the interests of pedantry, there are 16 ounces in a *US* pint, and it's reasonable to assume that the manuals use US measurements rather than (e.g.) Imperial ones. Thus British players don't need to use five vials to be the equivalent of a flask.